# Matrices with equal row and column sum

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I'm looking to integrate over the possible entries of an n*n matrix with the following constraints:

$a_{ij} \geq 0 \,\forall\, i,j$

$\sum_{ij} a_{ij}=1$

$\sum_i a_{ki} = \sum_j a_{jk}$

so matrices with non-negative elements which sum to 1, for which the kth column and the kth row have the same sum.

The integral is over $\prod_{ij} da_{ij}$ with these $n$ constraints (since the nth row/column sum is implied by the others).

Is anyone familiar with matrices of this form?

I'm looking to express the integral in a way that will allow me to numerically evaluate it iteratively.